# custom login module to access httpservletrequest in JBOSS EAP

Tags: httprequest, jboss7.x

I am developing a custom login module for jboss' jaas implementation. I would like to be able to access the HttpServletRequest object inside my login module. Does anyone know the best way to do this, if it's possible? I've been researching this, and so far I think I need to use a Callback of some kind, but I'm not sure.I found some WebSphere documentation that shows they have a WSServletRequestCallback that seems to be able to do this. Please suggest a simple example or documentation if jboss' jaas implementation have anything like this.

**Update:**

@kwart: As per your suggestion, I coded the following. Please suggest if this is the right way:

```
    protected CallbackHandler _callbackHandler;        
    HttpServletRequest request = null;
    ObjectCallback objectCallback = null;

    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[1];
    callbacks[0] = objectCallback = new ObjectCallback("HttpServletRequest: ");

    try
    {
        _callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASSNAME, METHOD_NAME, "Error handling callbacks", e);
    }

    try
    {
        if (objectCallback != null)
        {
            request = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
        }
    }
    catch (PolicyContextException e) {
        logger.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASSNAME, METHOD_NAME, "Error getting request", e);
        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASSNAME, METHOD_NAME, "Exception occured augmenting JbossSubject", e);
    }
```

Comment: You're basically re-inventing JASPI(C)'s `ServerAuthModule`s. Unless you're for some reason forced to use proprietary APIs, consider leveraging what's already included in Java EE instead.

Comment: Why the magic with ObjectCallback? You don't need it. The PolicyContext line is enough to retrieve the HttpServletRequest instance.

Comment: "jboss' jaas implementation"? Jboss doesn't implement jaas! It loosely re-uses some JAAS classes from the JDK...

Comment: A login module (identity store) should not need the request. Using that is the job of what JBoss calls the authenticator. If you're going to use a custom authenticator (authentication mechanism) you could better use a JASPIC SAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution from [this](https://developer.jboss.org/message/758628?_sscc=t#758628) site.

Used JSPI authentication. Configured an auth module in security domain in standalone as explained [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7EnablingJASPIAuthenticationForWebApplications) . 
Created a [custom authenticator](https://developer.jboss.org/message/758600#758600#758600) and a [custom login module](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/creating-a-custom-jboss-login-module), configured the authenticator in `jboss-web.xml` and login module in security domain in `standalone xml`.

I jar'd them in a separate module and added that to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Stored http request in `ThreadLocal` in the authenticator and retrieved it in my login module by simply reading the value stored in  the Thread Local.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **JACC PolicyContext** to retrieve the `HttpRequestObject` in the `LoginModule` methods:

```java
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext
    .getContext(HttpServletRequest.class.getName());
```

**Update:** Find sample usage in LoginModule [here](https://github.com/kwart/secured-webapp-template/blob/2228f502985ac244c014330e88fda968632da4c7/src/main/java/org/jboss/test/DummyLoginModule.java#L71-L97).

Comment: I used the above method to get the request object to my login module. Deployed this module to the server. But not sure how can I demo this to my team. Any ideas on how can I show them that the request object is retrieved.

Comment: JACC approach worked for me in JBOSS 6. But not working in JBOSS 7. Can you please let me know if there is an alternative for this JBOSS 7?

Comment: I tried it on EAP 6.3 and it works. I expect it's also working on JBoss AS 7.x. The product "EAP 6.x" is based on the community project "AS 7", so the behavior should be very similar. :) And the question talks about EAP 6.3

Comment: Sorry about the question. I just updated the title removing the version. The following jboss forum says its not working from 7: https://developer.jboss.org/message/721521#721521

Comment: JACC PolicyContext is required to be work by the Java EE spec, but the spec is not super clear if it should work outside its intended context (the JACC provider), but on JBoss it always does.

Comment: This worked right away on my Java EE 6 app on JBoss EAP 6.4.